# Why Debit MasterCard if there is already Maestro?

Tags: debit-card, mastercard, electronic-payment, eft

In some parts of the world MasterCard is offering its "Debit MasterCard" instead of or alongside its Maestro brand which is a debit only system.

Question is: **Which one has been there longer and why would they introduce the other one?** I suppose they are processed over two different systems but that is the only difference I see between a Maestro card and a Debit MasterCard.

Does anyone know about historical or other reasons for this?

Comment: Probably brand recognition. Even if the logo is the same, a person would take some time to assimilate that Maestro -> Mastercard. Also probably they are offering a multiple card (one that can work as both debit and credit).

Answer (score 1):

Different systems have different fees for merchants. In many cases an incumbent system will typically have higher fees simply because there is no competition.

Maestro also isn't used worldwide, so for the consumer in a "Maestro country", they now get more choice too to make their travel easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maestro, however, is a brand **by** MasterCard. They are not two different companies, they are two very similar - if not identical - products by the same company. That's why I'm asking. Your point about Maestro not being as widely used around the world as MasterCard itself is still valid, though.

Comment: @Arminius thanks , I should edit my answer, it is probably still more choice for the merchant.